# Are there supposed to be three different cream colors?

Tags: bug, design

After editing a question, I saw three different cream colors (see the screenshot below).

[image]

Are these colors supposed to be all different?  I feel like the site would look a bit spiffier if they were all the same color (and had consistent borders).

Comment: Disappointing ... expected ice cream ...

Comment: For me same color = same Flavor, If they had the same color those box I will expect them to have the similar content. So I won't ask for consistency on color, But for different color, or an Icon. But I have to agree that similar color and inconsistant border is disturbing.

Comment: @DragandDrop that's a valid point, but these colors don't seem differentiating (e.g. green for success, yellow for warning, blue for info, etc.) but clashing (i.e. we tried to make them the same color but didn't communicate well enough).  They should either be all the same exact color or obviously and intentionally different.